# What, and how would I create a script that moves certain files when opened?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, notepad

I have files in folder A, and I want to move them to folder B, as I put files in these folders often and usually need them moved between each other. They are deep in other folders, however, and I would like to write a simple bit of code (if possible, like in notepad) that I can make into a .exe and run, and have it move all the contents from Folder A to Folder B.

I don't know enough about Windows to know what language to use and even how I would start to write a code that told Windows to move the files.

Comment: At first you need to start learning to wrote programs. Almost every programming language which have a translator for windows can do it. After knowing the basics you can ask specific questions on stackoverflow.com. our,  if you don't want / have time to learn,  just hire a professional to do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple Batch script could work. For a detailed tutorial see [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/263177/how-to-write-a-batch-script-on-windows/). In your particular scenario, you could first create a text file like:

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO Moving files...
MOVE "C:\tmp\1\*" "C:\tmp\2\"
PAUSE
```

Then rename it to **movefiles.bat** (make sure to change the actual extension, not just the filename) and run it whenever you need to move the files.

Answer (score -2):

An **.exe** file is compiled from a programming language. A better alternative for you would be to create a **.cmd** - also known as a batch file - which is a script file you can schedule or double-click on that runs commands. You create this file is any **text editor** eg Notepad-type program (do not create in a wordprocessor like MS Word or it will add extra unseen characters to it).

Windows allows you to write your own simple commands this way, eg using the `copy` command. A set of examples for different tasks and how to start off is described on http://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/windows-10-command-line-tricks-1325962

Comment: This answer, in it's current form, does not answer the question that was asked.  It is far to broad and doesn't specifically address the author's question.  A explaination of what an compiled executable is exactly, and a vague suggestion to use one of the "examples" from a random link, does not answer the author's question